# Do I need to get a business license if I charge users to play on my Minecraft server?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, video-games

Mojang (the developer of Minecraft) has recently stated that server owners may charge users access to their server, so I know they allow it ([source](https://mojang.com/2014/06/lets-talk-server-monetisation/)). My only question is whether I need a business license to charge users access. Do I need to pay taxes on this as well? Even with my highest estimates, I would probably make less than $300/yr on this. The plan is simply to cover my costs of hosting it.

I'm located in California.

Users would pay me via PayPal (using BuyCraft's plugin or something similar to automate it).

Also, I have users that help me manage the server (ie. "staff"). The plan is to trade them free access in exchange for their help (banning abusive players, etc). Would I be able to do this?

Comment: Are you expecting somebody to issue you a tax form and report the transaction to the IRS?  Is the money routed through the developer or do you deal directly with the users?

Comment: @NL7 the fact that a tax form is not issued doesn't make it any less of a taxable income, does it? If he uses merchant account for donations (like paypal), he may end up with 1099-K.

Comment: You may not be allowed to trade free access, Mojang's policy on paid access indicates you can't not charge someone for any reason. You should probably email them to ask if paying staff with free access is an acceptable exception, otherwise you might have to reimburse them instead in order to be compliant.

Comment: @littleadv - No, the IRS doesn't as a rule let taxpayers make binding determinations about what is or isn't income, but it's useful for taxpayers to know how other parties will be accounting or reporting for transactions.  It may also tell us more details about the deal if we know what the other parties think about reporting it.  And my unstated implication was that... certain taxpayers... might make their reporting reflect the level of reporting by other parties.

Comment: It would not be routed through the developer of Minecraft. They would pay me via a plugin/service called BuyCraft which is connected to my PayPal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re the business license - in California business licenses are given by the municipal/county governments, so you'll have to check that with your city hall or county office.

Re taxes - yes, you'll have to pay taxes, as with any income. Services are considered "imputed income", and generally you'd recognize income to the extent they would be paying had they been paying the full price (or the actual cost of services provided, if more).

Since this is a hobby and not a for-profit enterprise, your deductions may be limited by the actual income and the 2% AGI threshold. See more [here](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch12.html#en_US_2013_publink1000172063).

Comment: Ok, just to clarify, you're saying I would need to pay taxes on the money I'm _not_ getting--the money that I _would_ be getting if my "staff" paid me for access the same as everyone else?

Comment: @user17550 technically yes

Comment: @littleadv - I might suggest you address the services issue as *barter*. Isn't that how such transactions should be treated given the situation?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer but expenses are limited.